# sun pkcs11 cannot derive key issue on RHEL8/Tomcat9

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat9

We just upgraded a RHEL 7 box to RHEL 8 (FIPS enabled).  We are running Tomcat 9.0.59 and the app connects backend to an Oracle 19c database across TCP port 1521.  Tomcat and the Application configs were not changed during the upgrade, Tomcat was installed outside of RHEL's patching system so it did not have any changes through the upgrade process.

The server is running openJDK java 1.8.0.392

We ran ACAS based scans and the server is secured against intrusion at a variety of levels.

The application, now, however, does not connect to the database.  The connection is still jdbc:oracle:thin:myserver.mydomain.com:1521:mydb but when the application tries to connect the stack dump shows:

java.security.ProviderExeception: Could not derive key

and digging down further I see reference to sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret

But the connection has nothing to do with pkcs11 - it is entirely a standard oracle 1521 connection.

We have looked at configs across the servers, we've checked Java security settings.
fips is enabled and pcks11 is set as the first security in java.security for FIPS, but we have another server that had a similar migration done a few months ago and there was no issue.  It also is fips enabled and has the same entries in java.security.